# Workaround needed for installing minimum OS 4.4 APK on 4.0.4 Android OS

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to install some APKs which have the minimum OS version parameter set to 4.4.4 KitKat and minimum SDK @16.
The platform is the Epson Moverio BT-200 see-through glasses which is basically a tablet.

More on the device:
https://www.cnet.com/products/epson-moverio-bt-200-smart-glasses-8-gb/specs/

The BT-200 itself comes without Google Play Store and needs to be rooted and Play Store installed. This part is done.

I also tried to install APKs and edit the build.prop file first. Set the OS version to 4.4.4 but got the exception that minSDK version criteria failed. Tried with ADB install as well. Of course when I set the SDK version in the build.prop file it ruined the installed apps and most of them freezed, suddenly stopped etc.

My question is, how could I "fool" the APK installer to install the APK(s) to get the programs running? Is there a way?

My reason: the BT-200 is a fantastic FPV device with android. The newest BT-300 model has android 5 but while this still works like a charm I'd spend my money rather on beers than another FPV glasses. :)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: sorry forgot the introduction - "hey guys, i need some help here :) "

Answer (score 0):

4.4.4 KitKat is api 19 , did you set your targetsdk to api 19 ? as for minsdk just change it to api 15 . the bt moverio from what i know is either api 15 or api 19, check on your bt moverio glasses what api it supports and then set the target sdk to that api.

Comment: hey, basically this is what i did, changed api to 16 in the editor, rebooted the moverio (requested by another app which i wanted to install) and basically ruined my system. epic slowness and almost all running programs were exiting with exception (sorry, google play stopped...)

Comment: i think i understand a bit better what you are talking about, try and use https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/ to get the apk you want from the url you want say this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en.Then install the apl on to the BT-200 . I know some apps won't download because of minsdk like you said , but I've had some success downloading apps onto the BT-200 using it.

Comment: yeah that page is nice thanks, i use apkpure.com and google for downloading the apks. my problem is that Moverio seems not installing at all because of the OS is too old and apk installer requires newer OS. that is my question really, how can i fool the apk installer that i would think that it is on newer OS? :) -if there is a thing like that.